# Change navigation bar button spacing / position in ios 7+

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would like to be able to move the buttons in 2 dimensions not only on the horizontal axis, yet a solution just for one would be highly appreciated.

I've seen many answers to this question, but none that fully worked, at least not on ios 7+.
Using a UIView and placing the button inside changes the touch area:

```
    var rightMoreBarButtonItem = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    var rightMoreBarButtonImage = UIImage(named: "ic_more_22px")
    rightMoreBarButtonItem.setBackgroundImage(rightMoreBarButtonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    rightMoreBarButtonItem.addTarget(self, action: "moreTapped", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    rightMoreBarButtonItem.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)
    var barButton1View: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22))
    barButton1View.bounds = CGRectOffset(barButton1View.bounds, -14, -7)
    barButton1View.addSubview(rightMoreBarButtonItem)
    var RightMoreBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: barButton1View)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = RightMoreBarButtonItem
```

Using fixedSpace works only for the first space for the rightBarButtonItem:

```
    var space1:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    space1.width = -16.0

    var space2:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    space2.width = 0.0

    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([space1, rightMoreBarButtonItem, space2, rightAddBarButtonItem ], animated: true)
```

I've tried changing the values for space1, space2 with no luck. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, but I'm new to Swift / Obj-C and I'm out of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should be using "SPACERS"**

(YES, this is ObjC, I'll try to come up with a Swift solution, but the only change you'll make is to create UIBarButtonItems using this "UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace"

**For example, this:**

```
_invitePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomething)];
_homePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomethingMore)];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_invitePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem, _homePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem, nil]];
```

**Produces this:**

[image]

Well that was obvious, right?

**Now, look at this with 1 SPACER:**

```
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

_invitePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomething)];
_homePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomethingMore)];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_invitePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem, spacer,_homePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem, nil]];
```

**Produces this:**

[image]

**And,it produces this HIT area:**

[image]

You'll notice, the very very thin lines, show the hit area of the UIBarButtonItems and they are just as they should be

**Now, consider this with 3 SPACERS:**

```
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

_invitePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomething)];
_homePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomethingMore)];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:spacer, _invitePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem, spacer,_homePlaceHolderForExampleBarButtonItem, spacer, nil]];
```

**Produces this:**

[image]

**And,it produces this HIT area:**

[image]

Just use various spacers and what not and stop meddling with trying to force a UIView into the navigation bar. Nearly everything that seems like something that Apple can't do is something that Apple already DOES. It's an issue of documentation and Apple could do a better job of pointing things out like this to developers instead of developers trying to hack around a solution, but I digress, this will work, just use what you already have in front of you.

This works:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.title = "Example"

        var img = UIImage(named: "thw")
        var space1:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        space1.width = 50
        var b = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "sayHello")
        var a = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "sayHello")
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([b, space1, a], animated: true)
    }

    func sayHello() {
        println("got here")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view?.backgroundColor = UIColor .redColor()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

produces this output, without subclassing:

[image]

You are going to have to mess around with the spacers to make this work, but this works. I don't have any more answers for you, you'll just have to tweak it here and there, but from the example I showed you before, you are using "fixed Width" spacers, I didn't use fixed width, even when I just defined the ones in the swift example as flexible, does this make a difference? I don't know, but it worked without shifting the title.

Comment: I've played with `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` but the problem is that the [navigation bar title isn't fixed](http://postimg.org/image/iuw54uufh/), and gets pushed to the left, while my 3 buttons are spread evenly across the remaining distance

Comment: Yes, but my title stays fixed, I can show you have this works but the solutions is very  very long, it doesn't require anything more than subclassing a sub class of a UIViewController, let me know if this is what you want because this solution is pretty intense but it's why my title doesn't move

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct as soon as I test the fix for the screen title as it will give me what I've wanted.

Comment: there's your answer, that's as far as I'm going to go with this one, you will have to tweak things just like I did in order to get it to work, but the above picture uses swift and doesn't shift the title.